# Using files in --onefile mode (auto-py-to-exe, pyinstaller)

Tags: python, file, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe

I'm trying to use images in --onefile mode for auto-py-to-exe script, but the Issues page only says:

> If you are using one-file mode, make sure you have followed the necessary steps.

The only instructions in the actual program are:

> Be careful when using additional files with onefile mode; read this and update your code to work with PyInstaller.
> If you want to put files in the root directory, put a period (.) in the destination.

Which doesn't help at all.

The files are being referenced like this:

```
img = pygame.image.load('image.png')
```

Which works in --onedir mode if I add `_internal\\` before the file name, which I have tried in --onefile mode.

Comment: from https://pyinstaller.org/en/v6.1.0/CHANGES.html?highlight=_internal#id3,which says, start on 20230922, onedir mode will move all the file(no include the exe file) into _internal dir by default. I meet it ,too.

Comment: Try to use a lower version, of pyinstaller